# How does "shashin yako" translate to "burn the pictures"?

Tags: volitional-form, inflection

Here's the clip from JoJo's adventures s3e33 where a character says "shashin yako, ne" and it's translated to "burn the photos".

https://gfycat.com/acidicdearestarctichare

I couldn't get google translate to think that "shashin yako" means burn the pictures.

I found similar and close words:

- 焼く yaku - which means bake or grill
- 焚く taku - which means burn

So I would understand if the character said "shashin yaku" but it really sounds like "shashin yako".

Am I just mishearing this? Is this some sort of accent that makes the "u" sound like an "o"? Is this an inflection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He's using the volitional form of 焼く which is 焼こう. The volitional form is used to indicate "will" in the general sense and when used in independent clauses, often is translated to "Let's do [something]". A perhaps more accurate translation of what the blob is saying would have been, "Let's burn the pictures."

You can learn more about it from [Tae Kim's guide](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/desire) or really any of the multitude of elementary Japanese learning sites.